# Parallel PostgreSQL Trigger Function

Tags: postgresql, function, parallel-processing, triggers

I have a trigger on a table that gets fired after a row is inserted or updated. The trigger calls a function that takes values from a JSONB column in the initial table and inserts records into five other tables.

The performance of this function has become a bottleneck. Since these five tables don't depend on each other, is it possible to execute these inserts in parallel, by somehow making the inserts in the function run simultaneously?

The PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/trigger-definition.html) states that if multiple triggers are specified on the same table, they run in alphabetical order. I assume one trigger would need to finish before the next one executes.

Comment: Right. There is no way to parallelize that.